# Javascript event handler on table?

Tags: javascript, html, events

Quick question, is it possible to put an onclick event handler on a  `<table>` element? At the moment I've got a handler on each `<tr>` to detect when a row is clicked, but I was thinking it would be simpler and more efficient if I could have a single event handler for the whole table and then use event.target to find which row was clicked.

Comment: No better way than to try it out...

Comment: What happens when you add an onclick to the `<table>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want event delegation:

jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

raw: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that.  The events will bubble from the row elements to the table.

You'll have to be sure and deal with the differences between the Internet Explorer event objects and those in other browsers. Specifically, the "target" isn't called that in IE; I think it's "srcElement" but I'll have to verify that. (*verified*)

Comment: Thanks, I asked as I've seen the question asked about how to detect a row being clicked and all the solutions involve putting a handler on each row. Also I wasn't sure if all browsers would support putting it on the table?

Comment: All browsers I know of do support this. Now, not all events work equally well on older browsers. This specific area of functionality is one of the things that the various JavaScript frameworks do a good job of "normalizing" across browsers.